# Zip file made in Powershell can't be used in Linux

Tags: linux, zip, encoding

I have a folder with subfolders and files. I create a .zip file via powershell's `Compress-Archive`.

Problem is that the file structure is messed up when opened in Linux.

Bad is the bad.zip archive made in Powershell with `Compress-Archive`,
and Good is good.zip made with Windows' WinRAR.

This is how it looks on Linux: (Left is bad, right is good)

[image: picture 1]

File contents seen in Linux with `cat`: (left is bad, right is good):

[image: picture 2]

**How to fix this problem??**

...

I tried replacing all "\" in bad.zip with "/" in nano and **it worked**.

I tried automating that with this script, but unsuccessfully:

```
#!/bin/bash

contents=$(cat $1)
echo "${contents//\\//}"
```

I run the script:

```
./FixZip.sh bad.zip > new.zip
```

The backslashes have been replaced, as intended, but new.zip cannot be opened. The reason is probably the encoding is different...

This is the encoding for the zip files:

```
terminal:# file -i bad.zip 
bad.zip: application/zip; charset=binary
terminal:# encguess bad.zip 
bad.zip UTF-32LE

terminal:# file -i new.zip 
new.zip: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
terminal:# encguess new.zip 
new.zip unknown

terminal:# cat new.zip
P5�WMCw:a_folder/test2.txt+��IP7�WM���a_folder/test3.txt�(*P4�WM��6a_folder/subf/test1.txt�H���P5�WMCw:a_folder/test2.txtP7�WM���7a_folder/test3.txt4�WM��6ma_folder/subf/test1.txtPKũ
```

Comment: `echo` and a shell variable is a cumbersome way to do a conversion. In this case even `tr` would be wrong because you need to fix the table of content or so, but not the binary data where backslashes may also occur. `cat`-ing to the console to check a binary file is also weird (hint: `xxd`). Back to the question, for a single file this may help: [Convert a Windows-created ZIP to Linux (internal paths issue)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166159/108618). I understand the best solution would be to create files that don't need to be fixed.

Comment: Are you the only person on this forum?... Anyways.. I cannot use 7zip on windows, only powershell's Compress-Archive. I guess I can always recreate the file structure with a script....

Comment: No offense intended. It's just that he always helps me..

Comment: Several things wrong: (1) you can't edit a zip file without corrupting it, which will normally be detected by its check-sum; (2) `$(cat $1)` will replace any sequence of white-space characters by a single space; (3) back-slashes will occur in the compressed data, as well as in the file index, so replacing them will further corrupt the file. It's not obvious why the `PK` magic number should have been replaced, but I would guess return, back-space or escape characters in the binary would account for it. As @KamilMaciorowski recommends, `xxd` will clarify what's going on.

Comment: "I cannot use 7zip on windows, only powershell's Compress-Archive." - really? You've already said you can use WinRAR. 7-Zip is available as a [Portable App](https://portableapps.com/), which doesn't need installation.

Comment: @AFH I only used WinRAR as a demonstration. I downloaded 7z as you said and it fixes the problem... but it's not exactly portable.. I have to install it first. using the GUI. However, I want to install and run it on the command line, so I'd like a single download&play 7z.exe file, or the like.

Comment: The version on the PortableApps web-site is completely portable. It can be launched either through the PA interface or directly from the `PortableApps\ ` directory, which contains 32- and 64-bit versions of both the GUI and the `7z.exe` command-line version, which I imagine will need one or more of the `.dll` files.

Comment: @AFH After having to install '7zip portable' from the website, I've moved 7z.exe and 7z.dll to another folder and deleted the main one. It still worked. That's portable enough for me. Thank you very much for the help. Please write the same thing as an answer so that I can nominate it.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27289115/1025421) with .NET prior to 4.6.1. PowerShell is of course somehow using an older version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with what you are trying to do - most significantly:-

1. You can't edit a zip file without corrupting it: this will normally be detected by its check-sum, and a corrupt file will be reported.
2. `echo $contents` (or other expansion variants) will replace any sequence of white-space characters by a single space.
3. Back-slashes will occur in the compressed data, as well as in the file index, so replacing them will further corrupt the file.

The most satisfactory answer is to use a cross-platform archiver, such as [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), which will save an archive with generic directory separators and will expand in the native format for the platform where it's called.

In Windows I use the [Portable Apps](https://portableapps.com/) version, which can be run through the PortableApps Suite interface, or direct from its directory in isolation; the portable version contains both 32- and 64-bit builds and includes `7z.exe`, the command-line interface (which may use a DLL from the same directory).

It's not obvious why in your logs the `PK` magic number should have been replaced, but I would guess that return, back-space or escape characters in the binary could account for it. As Kamil Maciorowski recommends in his comment, `xxd` will clarify what has been going on.

Answer (score 3):

Replacement Powershell Compress-Archive with call to 7zip utility (download 3rd party)

```
$folderPathToZip = "C:\MyFolder"
$fileName = "myFolderZipped.zip"
$DestPath = "C:\Destination\Path"
$DestPathPlusFile= "$DestPath\$fileName"

# CHANGE THIS POWERSHELL:
Compress-Archive -Path:"$folderPathToZip\" -DestinationPath:"$DestPathPlusFile" -Force
 
# TO THIS:
& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -o"$DestPath\" "$fileName" "$folderPathToZip\" -aoa
# a     = archive
# tzip  = normal .zip compression style
# -o    = DestinationPath
# -aoa  = Force
```